# sending email using database mail

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

How do I use database mail in SQL Server?
I have followed many articles on the forums but I failed with many errors.
I read in one book that I must have SMTP server and Microsoft Exchange
installed before I can use the database mail? Is this correct?

Comment: "many errors". Which errors did you get?

Comment: You need to have a running SMTP in order to relay the messages.

Comment: Microsoft Exchange is not required, although many organizations use Exchange as their SMTP server.

Answer (score 6):

Yes  SMTP server would be good to configure the database mail.

> Limitations and Restrictions Enabling SQL Server Service Broker in any
>   database requires a database lock. If Service Broker was deactivated
>   in msdb, to enable Database Mail, first stop SQL Server Agent so
>   Service Broker can obtain the necessary lock.

Also,

> To configure Database Mail you must be a member of the sysadmin fixed
>   server role. To send Database Mail you must be a member of the
>   DatabaseMailUserRole database role in the msdb database

Just for test, i am using below gmail server as smtp.

Please go through [this MSDN article on how to set up as well](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186358(v=sql.105).aspx)

Configuring Database Mail Using T-SQL Script

```
--Enabling Database Mail
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
reconfigure

--Creating a Profile
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profile_sp
@profile_name = 'SQLProfile',
@description = 'Mail Service for SQL Server’;

-- Create a Mail account for gmail. We have to use our company mail account.
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_account_sp
@account_name = 'SQL_Email_Account',
@email_address = 'youremail@gmail.com',
@mailserver_name = 'smtp.gmail.com',
@port=587,
@enable_ssl=1,
@username='youremail',
@password='Emailid password'

-- Adding the account to the profile
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profileaccount_sp
@profile_name = 'SQLProfile',
@account_name = 'SQL_Email_Account',
@sequence_number =1 ;

-- Granting access to the profile to the DatabaseMailUserRole of MSDB
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_principalprofile_sp
@profile_name = 'SQLProfile',
@principal_id = 0,
@is_default = 1 ;
```

--Sending Test Mail

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'SQLProfile',
@recipients = 'youremailid@xxxx.com',
@body = 'Database Mail Testing...',
@subject = 'Databas Mail from SQL Server';
```

--Verifying, check status column

```
select * from sysmail_allitems
```

Comment: sorry for delaying , I was sick, so I did not manage to reply, and thank you for your reply, when I run the above code, I got the following error             The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 1 (2015-04-27T05:17:58). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (The operation has timed out.).

Comment: Please send the screenshot of what you are using in database mail configuration wizard page/

Answer (score 0):

[image: this is the image]this is screen shots from the data base mail wizard!

Comment: the images did not appear correctly do you know how to add image?

Comment: Can you give a try with Anonymous authentication? Instead of basic authentication try anonymous and let me know what you see then!

Comment: thank you KASQLDBA for your post. I got the same error message. by the way, I have  smtp server but I did not configure it because I do not know how? please, tell me how to configure it